# What is the difference between suffix letters on Siemens circuit breaker panels?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

Can anyone explain what the meaning of the suffix letters "B" and "L" are on Siemens breaker panels?

For example, what is the difference between SN2040B an SN2040L?

Answer (score 7):

The difference is B = Main Breaker, L = Main Lug.

Ref: [Siemens Product Literature](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/14/1415b045-e021-4b28-89f2-aecc621becb1.pdf) page 8/9.

Comment: Can’t get more specific than that.

Comment: Sometimes a 2-line answer including a link is really all there is to it. And for those who complain about Big Orange, their website happens to be a great resource for finding product literature, though inconsistent - one panel product page will have the literature and warranty and installation PDFs and another (same brand) will have just the installation PDF, etc.

Comment: Page "2" (actual 4) [here](https://assets.new.siemens.com/siemens/assets/api/uuid:337a8594-9627-4af2-94a2-0b79f2182c40/sie-sa-espl-sel-app-guide.pdf) decrypts the entire model number.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Correct with respect to the B vs. L issue. But that document does not actually list the SN part numbers. As it turns out (for obvious and expected reasons), B vs. L means exactly the same in both documents, but they cover different products.

Comment: Yeah there's that. However in decrypting an SN I found they too conform to this format.